# Searching An object from @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA.

I an entity like this

```
public class A {

    @CollectionTable(name = "B_ITEMS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
    @ElementCollection
    private List<B> bs;

}
```

And an Embedded class

```
@Embeddable
public class B { 

private String prop1


private String prop2


private String prop3

}
```

How do I search entity A using the  contents @ElementCollection B?

And here's my repository  Spring Data JPA Repositry

```
public interface ARepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Clinic, Long> {

}
```

What Query method name is applicable for my use case?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking for a basic IN query in Spring Data - `findBybsIn(List<B> bs)`

Answer (score 4):

`@ElementCollection` is just a simple way to map a `@OneToMany` relation.

As such you can join them as usual:

```
public interface ARepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<A, Long> {
    @Query("select a from A a join a.bs b where b.prop1 = :prop1 and ...")
    A findByProps(@Param("prop1") String prop1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using @Query like in @Zeromus answer you can also define it by method name (findByElementCollectionProperty_NestedProperty):

```
public interface ARepo extends JPARepository<A,Long> {

    List<A> findByBs_Prop1(String prop1);
}
```

More information how SpringData resolves nested Properties can be found under:

[Query Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: how would this method look if Bs were not a collection of embeddables but a collection of simple Strings instead? Say, I want to know if a particular string argument matches with a string in the elementcollection. Would the method then look like this: `findByBsIn(String arg)` or should it be different?

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be to search a list of A objects for all the properties of B object. That means use filters for prop1, prop2 and prop3 together.

```
public interface ARepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Clinic, Long> {
    List<A> findByBsProp1AndBsProp2AndBsProp3(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3); 
}
```

Comment: this is a findby based on all the 3 properties of @Embeddable object. So if i need to search list of A for a specific object B, i can use this method and filter for all the properties, that means filter for the object itself.

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Also if i already explained in comments, i tried to improve the answer