# Querying an entity by values in an ElementCollections using Spring Data JpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to query entities in a JpaRepository based on values stored in an attached `@ElementCollection` using query methods?

**Setup**

My Spring Boot 2 / Spring 5 application has an entity (`Artwork`) to which arbitrary metadata can be attached. 
The metadata is implemented with a simple key value map using `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable`, since the metadata is just plaintext key/value pairs and does not exists outside the scope of it's entity.

The entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "artwork")
public class Artwork implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // more propperties 

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "artwork_metadata", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artwork_id"))
    private Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();

    // more code
}
```

**Problem**

I have two use cases, where I need to query the entity based on information stored in the metadata map.

- One use case is finding all `Artwork`s with licenses (having `metadata.name = license`, no matter what is in the value column)
- The other is finding all entities of one specific artist (having an exact key/value pair of `metadata.name = artist` and `metadata.value = someName`)

I have tried using the underscore notation for manual property path description; but my datatype is a map, not really an object with fields `name` / `value`.

```
public interface ArtworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Artwork, Long> {
    List<Artwork> findAllByReleaseDateAfter(Instant after);

    // Not working
    List<Artwork> findAllByMetadata_NameAndMetadata_value
```

Querying in general seems to be possible. But most of the answers I found on StackOverflow are about [searching in Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453191/searching-an-object-from-elementcollection), not in maps.

**So my question is**

How do I query entities in a JpaRepository based on values stored in an attached `@ElementCollection` using query methods? Or do I need to convert this rlationship at the object level using JPA’s one-to-many mapping.

**Update**

- Since we have several tens of thousands of recordsin the artist table I want to filter at the database level and not within the application.
- Querying by metadata will become common, so introducing helper flags like `hasLicense` or moving the artist to the primary entity is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: fetch all filter on application level?

Comment: That would not be efficient since we have several tens of thousands of records.

Comment: Consider that JPA is mainly suitable for CRUD. If your criteria can evolve based of future requirements other approaches may become more suitable (e.g. ElasticSearch for metdata + DB for entities). The first use case can be solved if you introduce "hasLicense" column in your JPA Entity and the fetching will be quick, but searching through the metadata for a match - if you want to keep it in the DB this should be separate table with FK to the main entity.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't plan on premature optimization. The metadata is in a separate table with a foreign key and, as stated, I want to query based on this information.

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.0 allows to use `KEY()` and `VALUE()` to refer to the key and value in map-based `@ElementCollection` in JPQL.

Normally , you can use them for solving your problem. However, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263725/jpas-mapkey-value-query-by-jpql-failed) , Hibernate seems to be a some strange behaviour for `VALUES()`...... Lucky , it has [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870824/339637).

Anyway , your problem can be solved by the following `@Query` (*Assume you are using Hibernate. If you use other providers , you can try `VALUES()`)*. :

```
public interface ArtworkRepository extends JpaRepository<Artwork, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select a from Artwork a join a.metadata meta where (KEY(meta) = :name)")
    public List<Artwork> findArtworkByMetadata(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query(value = "select a from Artwork a join a.metadata meta where (KEY(meta) = :name and meta = :value)")
    public List<Artwork> findArtworkByMetadata(@Param("name") String name, @Param("value") String value);

}
```

To find all Artworks with licenses :

```
artworkRepository.findArtworkByMetadata("license");
```

To find all Artworks of a specific artist:

```
artworkRepository.findArtworkByMetadata("artist" , "someName");
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising. I assume, `VALUES()` is optional in `(KEY(meta) = :name and meta = :value)`? I am running into some lazy initialization issues at the moment, but the generated sql looks good.

Comment: In `(KEY(meta) = :name and meta = :value)` , I did not use `VALUES()` since it has a problem in Hibernate as I mentioned.